# Moving to new domain

Tags: google-penguin-algorithm

One my site has been hit by Penguin penalty. Without waiting for next Penguin release  I want to move my site to another domain. Using 301 for pages could pass the penalty back to the new domain. I've done my best already by disavowing links.

**So what is the best way to divert traffic to my site without letting Google know?**

I could ask visitors to click on a nofollow link for the moved page. Or I could use Javascript to set the link target instead of using href in <a tag. But Google can figure this out.

Or I can use use a form submit button to be clicked to go the "moved" page.

So what is the best way in this situation?

Comment: Why not fix the reasons you got penalized instead of trying to game Google? If you don't fix the problems, you'll just get penalized again on the new domain and have to move again.

Comment: I've already disavowed all those bad links. But in the past it does not seem to have worked.

Comment: You may need to look at your site more critically.  If disavowing isn't working then you have more problems than just bad links.

Comment: I want to start from beginning again, what is the problem?

Comment: If you want to start from the beginning again you won't be trying to do it behinds Google's back. That's not starting over. That's trying to beat the system. You also have other issues then bad links. Until you resolve that you're just wasting your time.

Comment: It's only the bad links nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

> click on a nofollow link for the moved page

Google will crawl it 100%. It is long known fact.

> use Javascript to set the link target instead of using href in

Google is actively teaching to crawl javascript right now. You may use Jquery and AJAX constructions to block googlebot from following it. Just google it.

> use a form submit button to be clicked to go the "moved" page

Googlebot is able to submit forms.

My primary piece of advice (preferred) is to remove the penalty. Just disavowing will not help. You should try hard to delete every bad link manually by contacting webmasters of your link donors. If webmaster does not reply after a few attempts, then you should disavow the link with a comment about not replying. And the same for every link. It is really hard and boring, but it will help. Also you should look critically on your backlinks and delete all, which raise the smallest suspicion on spam. It should help.

If you don't want to do that, you may use my second piece of advice: Jquery+AJAX. It will 100% block googlebot from crawling it.

The third way is to use cloacking to redirect only users and not googlebot to your new site, but it may lead to permanent ban in Google.